# Azure SQL DB edit max text repl size

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am receiving the following error message in a mirror-database:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YcTZ.png)

sp_configure does not seem to be a stored procedure in Azure SQL DB. Can anyone help me understand how I can increase the configured maximum value for max text repl size?

Comment: Error message: Length of LOB data (321855) to be replicated exceeds configured maximum 65536. Use the stored procedure sp_configure to increase the configured maximum value for max text repl size option, which defaults to 65536. A configured value of .1 indicates no limit, other that the limit imposed by the data type.

Comment: Did you get a solution for your issue?

Comment: I was having this error as well. What I found was sp_configure and reconfigure are not supported on Azure SQL database. However, Azure sql managed instance supports sp_configure. You can try to exclude the column from capture if possible or if not look into temporal tables or change tracking

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue.

Having raised a ticket with MS, we were informed that they (ms ops somewhere) had changed the value for us.

[don't tell the dev team, we didn't know it was being acted upon, so they've recoded to avoid using CDC...]

IDK more, since I didn't personally raise the ticket...